# Conditional assignment based on environment variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, assignment

In a bash script, I'm assigning a local variable so that the value depends on an external, global environment variable (`$MYAPP_ENV`).

```
if [ "$MYAPP_ENV" == "PROD" ]
then
    SERVER_LOGIN=foobar123@prod.example.com
else
    SERVER_LOGIN=foobar987@test.example.com
fi
```

Is there a shorter (yet clean) way to write the above assignment? (Presumably using some kind of conditional operator / inline if.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could also use a case/switch in `bash` to do this:

```
case "$MYAPP_ENV" in
 PROD) SERVER_LOGIN="foobar123@prod.example.com" ;;
    *) SERVER_LOGIN="foobar987@test.example.com" ;;
esac
```

Or this method:

```
[ "$MYAPP_ENV" = PROD ] &&
   SERVER_LOGIN=foobar123@prod.example.com ||
   SERVER_LOGIN=foobar987@test.example.com
```

Comment: A case statement is far more readable than jamming it all into one line (which can end in catastrophe if the second command can fail, in this case, it is fine, but getting into that habit can be costly). This is the best method when dealing with cases like this.

Comment: I guess the case statement is the cleanest of the options presented, even if it isn't exactly what I was looking for. Oh well, Bash syntax is awkward, can't get around that. :)

Comment: @Jonik - that's been my finding as well. Believe me I've looked for alternatives, I prefer wide lines that do a lot rather than long programs, and the if/then/else is very verbose for my tastes too.

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
[ condition ] && var=value_when_true || var=value_when_false
```

If your assignment is numeric, you can use `bash` ternary operation:

```
(( assign_condition ? value_when_true : value_when_false ))
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `&&` and `||` operators

```
[ "$MYAPP_ENV" == "PROD" ] && SERVER_LOGIN=foobar123@prod.example.com || SERVER_LOGIN=foobar987@test.example.com
```